# I want to join the below three tables and get the sum of the income column

Tags: mysql

### Example Table

### Table1

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam |
| 2 | Anderson |

### PlanA_income

| ID | Income |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 1 | 300 |

### PlanB_income

| ID | Income |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 150 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 1 | 300 |

### I want the result to be like the below table

| ID | Name | sum of planA income | sum of planB income | Total Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 450 | 300 | 750 |
| 2 | Anderson | 25 | 175 | 200 |

### What I have tried:

1. I tried JOIN but It is not working while trying to join the complex queries.

### Description

1. I want to join the below three tables and get the sum of the income column.
2. I need the sum of planA table and planB table incomes separately and sum of the sums of both tables.

Comment: Aggregate each separate income table then join them to customers table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created your tables and ran the following query to make sure it is correct

go ahead

```
SELECT r1.id , r1.name, r1.sum_plan_a, r2.sum_plan_b, sum(r1.sum_plan_a + r2.sum_plan_b) 
from 
(
SELECT T.id, T.name, SUM(PA.income) as sum_plan_a 
FROM Table1 as T JOIN PlanA as PA 
on T.id = PA.id 
GROUP BY T.id 
)as r1 
Join 
(
SELECT T.id, SUM(PB.income) as sum_plan_b 
FROM Table1 as T JOIN PlanB as PB 
on T.id = PB.id 
GROUP BY T.id
)as r2 

on r1.id = r2.id 
GROUP by r1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID,
    t1.Name,
    SUM(a.Income),
    SUM(b.Income),
    SUM(a.Income) + SUM(b.Income)
FROM 
    Table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN PlanA_income AS a ON t1.ID = a.ID
    LEFT JOIN PlanB_income AS b ON t1.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate in `PlanA_income` and `PlanB_income` and do LEFT joins of `Table1` to the results of the aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(pa.sum_of_planA_Income, 0) sum_of_planA_Income,
       COALESCE(pb.sum_of_planB_Income, 0) sum_of_planB_Income,
       COALESCE(pa.sum_of_planA_Income, 0) + COALESCE(pb.sum_of_planB_Income, 0) total_income
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, SUM(Income) sum_of_planA_Income FROM PlanA_income GROUP BY ID) pa
ON pa.ID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, SUM(Income) sum_of_planB_Income FROM PlanB_income GROUP BY ID) pb
ON pb.ID = t1.ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=468f98a148a84020f2cf73720c14c1d2).